# Cascading Dropdownlist using ASP.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to get change Url if I select State from State dropdownlist, city from city Dropdownlist and Locality from Locality dropdownlist, browser Url should be changed as like Zipcode/statename/cityname/Localareaname. How to get this type of url from asp.net mvc using RouteConfig.

Controller Code:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string Search_name, int? page)
    {

        ViewBag.Title = "INDIAN Postal Codes";
        var StateList = objcity.GetAllStateName();

        model.StateList = StateList.Select(x =>
        {
            return new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = x.statename,
               //Value = x.statename.Distinct().ToString()

            };

        }).ToList();

        model.StateList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "--select--", Value = "0" });

        var CityList = objcity.GetAllCityName();

        model.CityList = CityList.Select(x =>
        {
            return new SelectListItem()
            {

            };
        }).ToList();

        model.CityList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "--select--", Value = "0" });

        var LocalareaList = objcity.GetAllLocalareaname();

        model.LocalareaList = LocalareaList.Select(x =>
        {
            return new SelectListItem()
            {

            };
        }).ToList();
        model.LocalareaList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "--select--", Value = "0" });


        //ViewData["Search_name"] = Search_name;
        List<usp_PostalcodeList_Fetch_Result> itmlist;
        //int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;

        Circuit9Entities db = new Circuit9Entities();
        //int pageSize = 10;

        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageIndex = 1;
        pageIndex = page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;

        int id = 0;
        itmlist = objcity.GetPostalCodeList(id);
        model.discountList = itmlist.Select(x =>
        {
            return new PostalCodeModel()
            {
                PostalCodeId = x.PostalCodeId,
                PostalCode = x.PostalCode,
                Taluk = x.Taluk,
                officename = x.officename,
                regionname = x.regionname,
                statename = x.statename

            };
        }).OrderByDescending(a => a.PostalCodeId).ToList();


        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Search_name))
        {
            model.pagePostalCodeList = model.discountList.OrderByDescending(x=>x.statename).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
            //model.pagePostalCodeList = model.discountList.ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, pageSize).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            //var students = from s in model.discountList
            //               select s;
            //model.pagePostalCodeList = students.Where(s => s.PostalCode.Contains(Search_name)).ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, pageSize);


            model.pagePostalCodeList = (from p in model.discountList
                                        where p.PostalCode.Contains(Search_name) || p.PostalCode.ToLower().Contains(Search_name.ToLower())
                                        || p.statename.Contains(Search_name) || p.statename.ToLower().Contains(Search_name.ToLower())

                                        select p).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);


            //model.pagePostalCodeList = jobSearchList.Where(k => k.JobName.ToLower().Contains(schKey.ToLower()) || k.JobDescription.ToLower().Contains(schKey.ToLower()) || k.JobSkill.All(x => x.SkillName.ToLower().Contains(schKey.ToLower()))).ToList();
        }    

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return PartialView("_PostalcodeList", model.pagePostalCodeList);
       else

           return View(model);
    }
```

public ActionResult GetDistrict(string statename)
        {

```
            int statId;

            List<SelectListItem> districtNames = new List<SelectListItem>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(statename))
            {

                var LocalareaList = objcity.GetAllLocalareaname();

                List<usp_City_GetAllCityName_Result> districts = db.usp_City_GetAllCityName().Where(x => x.statename == statename).ToList();

                districts.ForEach(x =>
                {
                    districtNames.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.regionname, Value = x.regionname.ToString() });
                });           

        }
            return Json(districtNames, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

jQuery code:

```
    function getCityList1(obj) {


        var selectedText2 = $("#ddlState option:selected").text();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Zipcode/GetDistrict",
            data: { statename: selectedText2 },
            datatype: "json",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {


                var localarea = "<select id='LocalId'>";
                localarea = localarea + '<option value="">--Select--</option>';

                var district = "<select id='CityId'>";

                district = district + '<option value="">--Select--</option>';

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    district = district + '<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option>';

                }

                district = district + '</select>';
                $('#CityId').html(district);                 


                $('#CityId').selectpicker('refresh');

                $('#LocalId').html(localarea);


                $('#LocalId').selectpicker('refresh');
                $('#LocalId').html('');
                //var localarea = "<select id='LocalId'>";
                //localarea = localarea + '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
                //localarea.html('');

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: can you provide some code that you're using now?

Comment: What does the supplied code do, and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: I need code for dropdown select state then statname should be display in the url. I have three Dropdown State City and Locality  if i select City then Cityname should be displayed in the Url like http://localhost:2042/Zipcode/statename/cityname/localareaname plz help me i am not getting proper code